# text box copy to searchbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy input of `text-box` to Google `search box` using copy button and by pressing Google search box button it should give search result.

here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/46n8kmgw/

Here copy button is working properly but I'm not getting search result

Here is code for search:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dp6r45c/

(Note: This code is not working on jsfiddle.net try it on pc )

Can any one help me to figure out what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the field name to `q`

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="textbox3" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
```

Comment: make .html file on your pc and run

Comment: but that's not problem

Comment: problem is in link no 1